# How do I correctly import libraries in React?

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I am trying to import the JS -[materialize](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) library. I installed it with npm,

then on my project root file `index.js` I tried this:

```
import materializeJS from 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js';

ReactDOM.render(<App M={materializeJS} />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

But when I try to initialize the select function in my `App.js` file:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { M } = this.props;
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
       var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
       var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, elems[0].children);
    });
}
```

`M` doesn't have any of the library functions. I also tried importing it with this

`import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js';` at the top of `index.js`

But didn't work.

Do I have to import this in `index.html` and then separately initialize all functions there ?

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct anwser to your question but they already have a [port for react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-materialize) and you will be better off installing it than using the regular js library in react.

Answer (score 1):

It can be tricky that's right.
I suggest you to use this react warper instead : [react-materialize](https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize)